# C# File.Copy Directory Not Found

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to do a `File.Copy` in C#.

I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.  However, I verified the directory exists.

My code:

```
try 
{
    log.Info("Copying file from '" + srcFile + "' to '" + destFile + "'");
    log.Info("Source File: '" + srcFile + "' exists: " + File.Exists(srcFile));
    File.Copy(srcFile, destFile, true);
    log.Info("Copied file to '" + destFile + "' success");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("Send Logs: Log file copy error", ex);
}
```

Results of running the code:

```
2017-08-30 09:20:25,933 [1] INFO  [ArbitrationForums.AFClient.AFSystemTray.MainForm] Copying file from 'C:\Users\ptenn\AppData\Roaming\ArbitrationForums\logs\AFDashboard.log' to 'C:\Users\ptenn\AppData\Roaming\ArbitrationForums\AFClient\DataSpool\AFDashboard.log'
2017-08-30 09:20:25,933 [1] INFO  [ArbitrationForums.AFClient.AFSystemTray.MainForm] Source File: 'C:\Users\ptenn\AppData\Roaming\ArbitrationForums\logs\AFDashboard.log' exists: True
2017-08-30 09:20:25,934 [1] ERROR [ArbitrationForums.AFClient.AFSystemTray.MainForm] Send Logs: Log file copy error
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
    'C:\Users\ptenn\AppData\Roaming\ArbitrationForums\logs\AFDashboard.log'.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String 
    destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
    at ArbitrationForums.AFClient.AFSystemTray.MainForm.sendLogs()
```

I should have permissions since I am logged on as the user that I am going to their `AppData\Roaming` Folder.

At wits end, does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Get rid of that `File.Exists()` check. It's really not helping you.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)? *The path specified in sourceFileName or destFileName is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).*

Comment: Very unlikely you verifed the directory `C:\Users\ptenn\AppData\Roaming\ArbitrationForums\logs\` exists for **all** of your users

Comment: Try running the program as admin and see if that makes any difference

Comment: Did you check if the destination directory actually exists?

Comment: Is this code in an interactive application or a service? It's a common pattern to have a tray app providing an interface to a service, but a service doesn't have your user's rights...

Comment: I'm with Timamonium on this one.  I'd suggest that your destination directory does not exist "C:\Users\ptenn\AppData\Roaming\ArbitrationForums\AFClient\DataSpool\"

Comment: @mjwills Then it may indeed be a permissions issue.  Try moving your source and destination to a new directory off the root like c:\temp and see if your issue goes away.

Comment: @DavidYates You were correct, the Destination Directory did not exist.  Could you please promote your comment to a reply and I will accept?  Thanks!  Still don't understand why the error insisted the Source Directory didn't exist though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with Timamonium on this one. I'd suggest that your destination directory does not exist "C:\Users\ptenn\AppData\Roaming\ArbitrationForums\AFClient\D‌​ataSpool\"

Comment: I have just encountered the very same issue.
It was the **DESTINATION** folder that did not exist.

The error message is very misleading!